# Perl module placing text in home folder

Tags: perl, module, makemaker

I am trying to create a Perl module with ExtUtils::MakeMaker. When installing it along with the module I need to place a text file containing some information in the user's home folder. How can I do this?

Comment: I'd be really unimpressed if a module started writing writing to ~/ during its install. Don't do that.

Comment: Makefile.PL is just a Perl program. You can do anything you like in it.

Comment: brian d foy, is absolutely right. I could simply put some codes in Makefile.Pl to write a text file in the Home folder.Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this

```
...
use File::HomeDir;

my $home = File::HomeDir->my_home;

open my $fh, '>', "$home/foo.txt";
print $fh 'bar';
close $fh;
```

I didn't test this because I'm currently under windows where File::HomeDir is not completely implemented

Comment: [File a bug!](https://rt.cpan.org/Dist/Display.html?Name=File-HomeDir) Unspecific complaints on a forum do not count.

Comment: You don't need to file a bug for that. It's documented already.